# finding distinct elements from two different parent tags using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to find distinct values from two different parent node from the below sample XML using XSLT 1.0 only. what I required was a template which is called for each `<one>` node by passing whole  as a parameter.
`<vln>` identifies each `<one>` node

Input:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <filename>
     <root>
       <vln>56837073</vln>
       <one>
         <vln>1233213427</vln>
         <Maddress>
           <address>
             <state>ak</state>
           </address>
         </Maddress>
         <Maddress>
           <address>
             <state>vr</state>
           </address>
         </Maddress>
         <co>
           <Maddress>
             <address>
               <state>fg</state>
             </address>
           </Maddress>
           <Maddress>
             <address>
               <state>ak</state>
             </address>
           </Maddress>
         </co>
       </one>
       <one>
         <vln>6785475239</vln>
         <Maddress>
           <address>
             <state>pp</state>
           </address>
         </Maddress>
         <Maddress>
           <address>
             <state>fg</state>
           </address>
         </Maddress>
         <co>
           <Maddress>
             <address>
               <state>fg</state>
             </address>
           </Maddress>
           <Maddress>
             <address>
               <state>ak</state>
             </address>
           </Maddress>
         </co>
       </one>
     </root>
   </filename>
```

output:
1.ak, vr, fg

2.pp, fg, ak

3....continues depends on no of `<one>` nodes

I tried all the ways that I understood following various tutorials. What I achieved is finding individual parent distinct values using http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html but when combined I have no idea. Help me out with this.

my code:

```
<xsl:key name="product" match="one/Maddress/address/state/text()" use="." />
<xsl:template match="one">
          <xsl:for-each select="one/Maddress/address/state/text()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('product',.)[1])]">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              <text> </text>
          </xsl:for-each>

<xsl:key name="product2" match="one/co/Maddress/address/state/text()" use="." />        
<xsl:template match="two">
          <xsl:for-each select="one/co/Maddress/address/state/text()[generate-id() = generate-id(key('product2',.)[1])]">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              <text> </text>
          </xsl:for-each>
```

Here one and two templates are called to check distinct values from two different parent nodes. 
Achieved output:

1.ak, vr, fg, ak
2.pp, fg, fg, ak

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what you have tried, please? Thank you!

Comment: is your  requirement is text format?

Comment: @AmrendraKumar, not a text format I am checking for distinct values in plain HTML format just a simple transformation of XML into HTML

Comment: @TimC this is what I did to get distinct values from different parent tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get distinct states per `one` element. This means you need to use a concatenated key

```
<xsl:key name="product"  match="state" use="concat(ancestor::one/vln, '|', .)" />
```

This assumes the `vln` is unique for each `one` node.

Then, within each `one` node, you get the distinct states like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//state[generate-id() = generate-id(key('product', concat(ancestor::one/vln, '|', .))[1])]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:key name="product"  match="state" use="concat(ancestor::one/vln, '|', .)" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/one" />
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="one">
  <xsl:value-of select="vln" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select=".//state[generate-id() = generate-id(key('product', concat(ancestor::one/vln, '|', .))[1])]">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank u for the answer it really worked I missed this ancestor::one/vln part and simply writing one/vln

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is text then you can use below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(//state)" separator=", "/>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake not to mention that I can only use XSLT 1.0